# Mathematical operation to reflect loop iterator about midpoint of number of iterations

Tags: algorithm, loops, sorting, fortran, countdown

Imagine we have a loop with index variable `n` counting from 1 to 6. As I got through this loop I want to print the values

```
1
2
3
3
2
1
```

Is there a elegant mathematical operation (i.e. avoiding `if` statements) which can implement this? I know for example if I print

```
1 + modulo(n-1,3)
```

it would print

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

but I want that second half reversed. The loop will always have an even number of iterations if that helps. I am writing in Fortran 90.

Comment: Can you give an overview of which functions and operators would be acceptable and which would be too expensive? (Absolute value, sign, square root, square, division, integer division, modulo, multiplication, floor/round/ceil, bitwise and/or/xor, bit shift, using floats, ...)

Comment: Would min(n, 7-n) be acceptable? It will produce 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 as n goes from 1 to 6.

Comment: @m69 I didn't have any particular thought as to the expense.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia that works perfectly, thank you, if you want to write that up as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a micro-optimization for speed.

Comment: @Kai Thanks, done.

Comment: @Kai You have got answer with `min` and `abs` in 10 minutes after asking. Have you read answers?

Answer (score 2):

How about the following:

```
do i=1,n
   print *, int(abs(i-n/2.0-0.5)+0.5)
end do
```

This will print the expected result for even `n` and introduces a ZERO for odd `n`.

Answer (score 2):

Is the following elegant enough? I think this is much clearer than obfuscated maths

```
ian-admin@agon ~/work/stack $ cat merge.f90
Program test
  Implicit None
  Integer :: n
  Integer :: i
  Write( *, * ) 'n?'
  Read ( *, * ) n
  Do i = 1, n
     Write( *, * ) Merge( i, n - ( i - 1 ), i <= n / 2 )
  End Do
End Program test
ian-admin@agon ~/work/stack $ gfortran -std=f2003 -Wall -Wextra merge.f90 
ian-admin@agon ~/work/stack $ ./a.out
 n?
6
           1
           2
           3
           3
           2
           1
ian-admin@agon ~/work/stack $ ./a.out
 n?
7
           1
           2
           3
           4
           3
           2
           1
ian-admin@agon ~/work/stack $
```

Comment: Thanks, this is nice and easy to understand, I didn't know about `merge`

Comment: `merge` selects between two values or between corresponding elements in two arrays, according to the condition specified by a logical mask. For more info and examples, see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/693255).

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
min(n, 7-n)
```

This expression produces `1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1` as `n` goes from `1` to `6`. More generally, if `N` is the (even) upper bound for the variable `n`, the formula becomes:

```
min(n, N+1-n)
```

which produces

```
1, 2, ..., N/2, N/2, N/2 - 1, ..., 2, 1
```

as `n` runs between `1` and `N`.

In the case where `N` is odd, the same formula generates the sequence

```
1, 2, ..., (N+1)/2, (N-1)/2, ..., 2, 1.
```

For example:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

for `N=7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 6 
for i in range(1,n+1):
   print(min(i, n + 1 - i))
      or (// is integer division equivalent to bitshift right) 
   print(n//2 - abs(n + 1 - 2 * i)//2)

>> 1 2 3 3 2 1
```

For odd length - the first approach works as is, the second way requires changing to `(n+1)//2` (it does not break work for even length)

Bit trick to find min of two 32-bit integers:

```
min = b+((a-b)&((a-b)>>31))
```